# Sum of two different freedom degree multivariate t distributions

Tags: distributions, multivariate-normal-distribution, t-distribution, multivariate-distribution

There are two multivariate t distributions whose freedom degree $\nu$ are different to each other.

$$
\mathbf{x} \sim \mathcal{T}(\nu_x, \mathbf{0}, \Sigma_x)
$$

$$
\mathbf{y} \sim \mathcal{T}(\nu_y, \mathbf{0}, \Sigma_y)
$$

Then, consider the sum of them

$$
\mathbf{z} = \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{y}
$$

What the distribution of $\mathbf{z}$ will be?

$$
\mathbf{z} \sim \mathcal{T}(\nu_z, \mathbf{0}, \Sigma_z)
$$

How can I express $\nu_z$ and $\Sigma_z$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking and unlike the normal distribution, the sum of $t$ random variables **is not** a $t$ random variable. In the univariate case, such a sum has the [Behrens–Fisher distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behrens%E2%80%93Fisher_distribution). You can read some more [here](https://doi.org/10.2307/2286298) (requires access).

Comment: Thank you very much.